# Hello Every one, How can i provide security by using spring in the application by folder wise

Tags: spring

[image]
Above image is the springsecurity.xml file.

[image]

Above image is the folder wise I written.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although we would love to help you, this is not a place to ask others to write code for you. We can only help you get past specific issues with your code. That will require you to post your code, what you expect it to achieve and where you are having problems. You will also benefit from going through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask good questions that others here will be willing to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope what you are trying to achieve is restricting access based on user role. You can intercept each incoming request and check if the user who is trying to access the url has required role to perform this operation. Please read this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html) and develop your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Valath, I done whatever you said, but my issue was not solved. Now I taken access="ROLE_SUPER_USER" . Please suggest..

Comment: please elaborate what you are trying to achieve